# javascript for onClick not executing?

Tags: php, javascript, html

ok maybe i must put all my code:

```
<?php
include('header_application.php');
$obj_clean->check_user();
$limit = 10;
if(!isset($_GET['page']))
  $page = 1;
else
$page = $_GET['page'];

$from = (($page * $limit) - $limit);
$msg = "";
if (isset($_GET['unblock']))
{
  $code = $obj_clean->unblockUser($_GET['unblock'],$_GET['code']);
  if ($code == "error")
  {
     $msg = "Could not delete message!";
  }
  else
  {
    $msg = "You have unblocked ".$code;
  }
}

//Get dynamic data required for this page from the database
$users = $obj_clean->getContacts($_SESSION['user_id'], $from, $limit);
$rows = $obj_clean->getContactsCount($_SESSION['user_id']);
include ("header.php");
?>
<div class="innerContainer">
<head>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
function yesnolist(val)
{
 var e = confirm('Do you want to send a free chat request?');
 if (e == true)
 {
    window.location.href = "http://www-rainbowcode-mobi/confirmfreechat.php";
    //window.location('http://www-rainbowcode-mobi/confirmfreechat.php');
    return true;
 }
  else
    return false;
 }     
</script>  
</head>
<span class="headings2">CONTACTS</span>
<?php if (isset($msg) && !empty($msg)) echo "<br/><font color='red'>".$msg."</font>"; ?>
<br/><br/>
<?php
if (count($users) > 0)
{
    echo "<table width='100%' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' border='0'>";
    foreach ($users as $user)
    {
        //Breaks the unique code into 3 parts so that the numeric part can be a different colour
        $codeLength = strlen($user['unique_code']);
        $firstPartLength = $codeLength - 5;
        $uniqueCode3 = substr($user['unique_code'], -2);
        $uniqueCode2 = substr($user['unique_code'], -5, 3);
        $uniqueCode1 = substr($user['unique_code'], 0, $firstPartLength);
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>';
        echo '<a class="charcoal_link" style="line-height: 20px;" href="'.ADDRESS.'view_profile.php?id='.$user['profile_id_contact'].'">'.$uniqueCode1.'<span class="pink_text">'.$uniqueCode2.'</span>'.$uniqueCode3.'</a>';
        $requestor_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
        $profile_id = $user['profile_id_contact'];
        $rel1 = $obj_clean->hasRelation($requestor_id,$profile_id);
        $rel2 = $obj_clean->hasRelation($profile_id,$requestor_id);
        if($rel1 && $rel2) 
        {
          echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;";
          //echo '<a href="confirmfreechat.php?id='.$profile_id.'" onClick="yesnolist()">Free Chat</a>';
          echo '<a href="#" onClick="yesnolist(); return false;">Free Chat</a>';
        }
        echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
else
{
    echo "You have no contacts yet";
}
?>
</div>
<?php include("footer.php"); ?>
```

hope this will help better

Comment: What errors are you getting in your error console? Why do you have a `div` element before `head`? That is not valid. Where does your `body` tag begin?

Comment: Don't know if this is just a in issue of the above example and your actual code is correct, but the last line should be inside a <?php ?> block. Moreover, I quote Pekka: tell us what happens in the error console and write a cleaner test case.

Comment: @Pekka: `body` element, sir, `body` element. [Tag is not an element. Or is it?](http://perfectionkills.com/tag-is-not-an-element-or-is-it/)

Comment: ok maybe i must put all my code:

Comment: @HelloiseSmit: Please format it correctly so that other people can read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
function yesnolist()
{
    if (confirm('Do you want to send a free chat request?'))
        window.location = "http://www-rainbowcode-mobi/confirmfreechat.php";
}
```

.
.
.

```
<a href="#" onClick="yesnolist()">
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<a href="" onClick="yesnolist()">Free Chat</a>

should be:

<a href="#" onClick="yesnolist(); return false;">Free Chat</a>
```

Comment: (you want to return false regardless of the outcome of the function call so that the click event is cancelled and therefore the page isn't left before your js function is called)

Answer (score 0):

I'd assume changing the URLs to valid domains might help things, so try:

```
window.location.href = "http://www.rainbowcode.mobi/confirmfreechat.php";
window.location('http://www.rainbowcode.mobi/confirmfreechat.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function yesnolist()
{
  var e = confirm('Do you want to send a free chat request?');

  if (e == true)
  {
    window.location = "http://www-rainbowcode-mobi/confirmfreechat.php";
    return true;
  }
  else
    return false;
}
```

and

```
<label onClick="return yesnolist();">Free Chat</a>
```

You can not pass onclick event on (a href="") tag because href part redirects the page and after that the javascript redirect part is called.

Or

```
(a href="#" onclick="return yesnolist();")Free Chat(/a)
```